# Why isn't TinyMCE 5 rendering formatted html on page and in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am programming newbie and I need your help.

I'm coding my first project and I ran across problem.

I needed text editor so I included TinyMCE 5. I'm coding in JavaScript and using mongoDB.

I included tinyMCE like this

`<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=your_API_key"></script>`

Everything works fine, https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrGRj.jpg

Until I try to save it to the mongoDB database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkYH0.jpg

and render it on the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lICMI.jpg.

This is code I managed to grab from other StackOverflow post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mcRr.jpg

My goal is to render text on page(in ejs file), without html tags.

Thank you for your help,

Marian

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting plain html to write the textarea tag:

```
<textarea>
  <p><strong>This is the strong text</strong><br></p>
</textarea>
```

So don't use the set the init_instance_callback, instead write the html to the textarea tag.

If you use the init_instance_callback, make sure ur template write only plain html.